# Обновлениие базы данных

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Объясните, пожалуйста, переменные `@FName`, `@LName` и тд это тоже что и `customersRow[0]`, `customersRow[1]` и тд?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
 
namespace Updates
{
    static class CustomersUpdates
    {
        private static void ChangeCustomers(DataRow customersRow)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
 
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 
            string commandString = "UPDATE Customers " +
                                   "SET FName = @FName," +
                                   "LName = @LName," +
                                   "MName= @Mname," +
                                   "Address1 = @Address1," +
                                   "Address2 = @Address2," +
                                   "City = @City," +
                                   "Phone = @Phone," +
                                   "DateInSystem = @DateInSystem " +
                                   "WHERE CustomerNo = @CustomerNo"; //обновятся все данные независимо от того какие записи изменим. 
            //Но изменится только та вставка где CustomerNo = нашему входному параметру (видимо который прописан в источнике).
 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerNo", customersRow[0]); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", customersRow[1]);      
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", customersRow[2]);     
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MName", customersRow[3]);     
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address1", customersRow[4]);   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address2", customersRow[5]);   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", customersRow[6]);      
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", customersRow[7]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateInSystem", customersRow[8]);
 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            customersRow.AcceptChanges();
        }
 
        public static void ChangeCustomers(DataTable customers) //перегрузка метода описанного выше
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in customers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified) 
                    ChangeCustomers(row);                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//EditCustomerDialog
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Updates
{
    public partial class EditCustomerDialog : Form
    {
       // DataTable table;
        DataRow rowToEdit;

        public EditCustomerDialog( DataRow rowToEdit)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            this.rowToEdit = rowToEdit;
            //this.table = table;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                rowToEdit["FName"] = textBox1.Text;
                rowToEdit["LName"] = textBox2.Text;
                rowToEdit["Address1"] = textBox3.Text;
                rowToEdit["City"] = textBox4.Text;
                rowToEdit["Phone"] = textBox5.Text;

                CustomersUpdates.ChangeCustomers(rowToEdit.Table);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            this.Close();

        }

        private void EditCustomerDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = rowToEdit["FName"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = rowToEdit["LName"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = rowToEdit["Address1"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = rowToEdit["City"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = rowToEdit["Phone"].ToString();
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

```
//Form1
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Updates
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string commandString = "SELECT * FROM Customers";

        DataTable customers = new DataTable("Customers");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
            adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

            adapter.Fill(customers);

            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var editDialog = new EditCustomerDialog((dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row);

            editDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну это вы в них такие значения помещаете. Это не "одно и то же", а вы в эти переменные SQL размещаете такие вот значения.

Comment: Это у Вас update команда с параметрами. Которые вы заполняете из колонок.

Comment: Что Вам не понятно? Вы путаете некоторые моменты. Таблица в Базе Данных это структура. А в приложение это его копия так сказать. После того как вы изменили копию вы синхронизируете изменения посредством SqlCommand

Comment: Оформить ответ или так понятно?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду колонки базы в источнике?

Comment: "Ну это вы в них такие значения помещаете. Это не "одно и то же", а вы в эти переменные SQL размещаете такие вот значения." Вы имеете ввиду переменные те которые с символа "@ " начинаются или те которые слева от "="?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте начнем работать с начала. У вас небольшой диссонанс, но я постараюсь объяснить.

1. Приложение Ваше работает с данными, которые оно загружает из Базы Данных. Скорее всего у Вас есть `DataGridView` которому нужно указать источник данных DataSource.
2. Взяв копию данных оно позволяет их изменить, `DataGridView`, `EditCustomerForm` ...
3. После локальных изменений (т.е. которые только у вас). Данные нужно синхронизировать с исходной Базой Данных вызывать метод `ChangeCustomers(DataGridView.DataSource.Tables[0])`, иначе ваши изменения пропадут после закрытия приложения.
4. Метод ChangeCustomers получив данные начинает обрабатывать таблицу по каждой записи

   ```
        foreach (DataRow row in customers.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified) 
                ChangeCustomers(row);                   
        }
   ```

а уже `ChangeCustomers(row)` сохраняет через `SQLComand` вашу измененную запись при этом заполнив необходимыми данными для изменения.

Как-то так думаю.

Правильно ли понимаю переменные `@FName, @LName` этот имена столбцов в источнике?

Нет это наименование переменных или параметров как вам удобно - которые будут заменены в команде после

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", customersRow[1]);
```

Грубо говоря

```
         string commandString = "UPDATE Customers " +
                               "SET FName = @FName," +
                               "LName = @LName," +
                               "MName= @Mname," +
                               "Address1 = @Address1," +
                               "Address2 = @Address2," +
                               "City = @City," +
                               "Phone = @Phone," +
                               "DateInSystem = @DateInSystem " +
                               "WHERE CustomerNo = @CustomerNo";
```

превратится после `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", customersRow[1]);` в это

```
        string commandString = "UPDATE Customers " +
                               "SET FName = " + customersRow[1].value + "," +
                               "LName = @LName," +
                               "MName= @Mname," +
                               "Address1 = @Address1," +
                               "Address2 = @Address2," +
                               "City = @City," +
                               "Phone = @Phone," +
                               "DateInSystem = @DateInSystem " +
                               "WHERE CustomerNo = @CustomerNo";
```

Comment: я добавил еще две формы этого кода. Но там нет копирования таблицы из источника

Comment: Можете запустить этот код?

Comment: есть SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
            adapter.Fill(customers);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;

Comment: а в commandString лежит SELECT * FROM Customers

Comment: забыл про строчку DataTable customers = new DataTable("Customers"); Это создание пустой таблицы, а adapter.Fill(customers); заполнение таблицы